# army surplus T-shirts -- "surplus"? why not just "army T-shirts"?

Tags: meaning

Example with a context ([Full-house in Kiev bar inspired by Russian propaganda](http://news.yahoo.com/full-house-kiev-bar-inspired-russian-propaganda-034037897.html)):

> Those aspects of the decor clash with new additions, like posters showing fighters of the nationalist Azov battalion and the **army surplus T-shirts** worn by the waiters.

I know what typical army T-shirts look like, but I'm not really sure what *army surplus T-shirts* are. Well, according to the picture (taken from the news article), they look just exactly like the regular army T-shirts. But, why do we say *surplus* then?

[image: a picture from the news article]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Army surplus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_surplus), according to Wikipedia, refers to items, such as uniforms, that are extra ("surplus") and the army isn't using.

So, while an "army T-shirt" might look exactly the same, the implication is that it is currently being used by the army. An "army surplus T-shirt" though is a shirt that was most likely extra (or they finished using).